# SignalR delay start in javascript client

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, signalr

I am banging my head against a wall trying to separate signalr from the $(function () event. I want to be able to start my signalr connection on demand from an external script (this is currently in a requirejs module). Here is my code:

main.js

```
uiShow = function (show, inFullpage) {
    //Start SignalR here
    //more code here removed
```

sr.js

```
$(function () {
    var srhub = $.connection.chatHub;
    $.connection.hub.url = 'url here';
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {});
    /more code here removed
};
```

The problem is that I have been unable to find a way to access the connection object from within main.js or anyway to trigger the connection of signalr from main.js.

What I want is something like this:

main.js

```
uiShow = function (show, inFullpage) {
    chatconnect();
    //more code here removed
```

sr.js

```
$(function () {
    var srhub = $.connection.chatHub;
    $.connection.hub.url = 'url here';
}

function chatconnect() {
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {});
}
```

The $.connection object is not accessible anywhere other than during the load of the script though so I cannot get it to work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Curiosity, did you configure the /signalr/hubs endpoint in requirejs too?

Comment: At first yeah, and just about got it working but moved back to outside requirejs because of this issue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about defining the hub globally so you can use anywhere?

```
var srhub = $.connection.chatHub;

$(function () {
    $.connection.hub.url = 'url here';
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {});
    /more code here removed
};
```

Comment: This was the issue, thanks! - for others with this issue then declare a global conn object and assign $.connection to it in the $(function () and do the same with srhub as per kravits comment. You can then access this from a function with conn.hub.start().done(function () { });